# compare 2 cell with identical date not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, compare

I have a spreadsheet with a cell, lets say range40, that contain the formula: `=today()` and another one that I set using script: `range39.setValue();`

Then in my script, I will compare those cell. Actually, I need to explain, if the both cell are different, I set the cell of `range39 =` to `range40.getValue().`

So, if the date change, I run some script and set the date to the new one, preventing this part of the script to run until next day.

```
My script is: 

var dat1 = range39.getValue();

    var dat2 = range40.getValue();

    if(dat1 != dat2){
    }
```

and the both cell are equal, even in the debugger, but the script still running!

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `getDisplayValue` instead of `getValue`

Comment: it does not work. I find out that with dat1.getTime and dat2.getTime it works but ask me to declare getTime property. Not sure if its working or just a temporary solution! I think I would know it tommorow!

Comment: @Marios it works with your tricks now! I dont know what I was doing wrong! Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now with Marios solution, `getDisplayValue`

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

First, you need to convert your values into `Date` objects:

```
var date1 = new Date(dat1);
var date2 = new Date(dat2);
```

And `getTime()` is a method, thus you need a null parameter () to have it interpret correctly.

So in your code it would be:

```
if (date1.getTime() != date2.getTime()) {
// do something
}
```

### Sample Code:

```
function dateCompare() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var range1 = sheet.getRange("A1");
  var cell1 = range1.getValue();
  var range2 = sheet.getRange("A2");
  var cell2 = range2.getValue();

  var date1 = new Date(cell1);
  var date2 = new Date(cell2);

  if (date1.getTime() != date2.getTime()) {
    console.log("Unequal dates");
    range2.setValue(cell1);
  }
}
```

**Date was replaced:**

[image]

**Console Log:**

[image]

### Reference:

[getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: still not able to get it work! For now I have: var dat1 = range39.getValue();
    var dat2 = range40.getValue(); and still always equal...

Comment: You need to convert them into ````Date```` objects first, e.g. ````var date1 = new Date(dat1);```` Edited answer.